# Does the backstack only exist in the FragmentManager instance?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

So if for example I had 4 fragment managers, would there be 4 seperate back stacks to handle?

Im looking to create a tabbed application that uses a bottom nav bar to switch between fragments. But within each tab the user can progress through to different areas of the app. I need it so that no matter how far they get in to a tabs flow, if they clicked on another tab, then came back to the previous tab, they would still be at the same place they left off.

So would using multiple `FragmentManager` instances (one for each tab) solve my issue?

In my case I have 4 fragments, one for each tab. So if im on tab 1 and go to fragment 4 in tab 1, if I then tap tab 3 and go to fragment 2 in tab 3, if i then go back to tab 1, i should still see fragment 4 of tab 1. But im not sure how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine using two `Fragment` instances for the tabs in the nav bar, and use each tab `Fragment`'s [getChildFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) method

Comment: I used the 2 fragments as an example, theres actually 4. So if im on tab 1 and go to fragment 4 in tab 1, if I then tap tab 3 and go to fragment 2 in tab 3, if i then go back to tab 1, i should still see fragment 4 of tab 1. But im not sure how to set this up. Do you know of any examples i could use?